# update specific data for an object using POST method in spring boot rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I want to update specific data only `name` field for a restaurant object. The way I want to make it that if a field is **empty or null**, just leave the old value.

Is there any good solution?

Note that I'm making a rest api app with Spring Boot.

**Restaurant.java:**

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "The restaurant must have a name")
    private String name;

    @NonNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please add a description for this restaurant")
    private String description;

    @NonNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "The restaurant must have a location")
    private String location;
}
```

**My post update function:**

```java
@PostMapping("/restaurant/{id}/update")
public Restaurant updateRestaurant(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Restaurant restaurantDetails, BindingResult bindingResult) {     
    Optional<Restaurant> restaurantOptional = restaurantService.findById(id);

    if (restaurantOptional.isPresent()) {
        Restaurant restaurant = restaurantOptional.get();
        restaurant.setName(restaurantDetails.getName());
        restaurant.setLocation(restaurant.getLocation());
        restaurant.setDescription(restaurantDetails.getDescription());
        logger.info("restaurant information edited successfully");
        return restaurantService.save(restaurant);
    } else
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to this question:

[Spring REST partial update with @PATCH method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200142/spring-rest-partial-update-with-patch-method/45200650)

In REST, a POST is usually for resource creation, not updates. A PUT method is usually used for updates when you want to update the entire resource. And a PATCH method is used for partial updates.

You want to use a PATCH and then only update the fields that are present in the request body.

It's a little easier if you change your @RequestBody to a `Map` instead of `Restaurant` because if you use `Restaurant` you can't tell if the client is trying to set the value to null or not.

```
    @PatchMapping("/restaurant/{id}/update")
public Restaurant updateRestaurant(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Map<String, Object> restaurantDetails, BindingResult bindingResult)
{
       
            Optional<Restaurant> restaurantOptional = restaurantService.findById(id);

            if (restaurantOptional.isPresent()) {
                Restaurant restaurant = restaurantOptional.get();

                // loop through the map keys here and only update the values that are present in the map. 

                logger.info("restaurant information edited successfully");
                return restaurantService.save(restaurant);
            } else
                return null;
        }
```

Comment: I updated the answer from PostMapping annotation to PatchMapping