# data is duplicating instead of updating

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i'm making a simple application and for some reason, instead of updating the current patient, i get duplicated code.[first created data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoLee.jpg) [when i change data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDAXb.jpg)

patient entity:

```
package com.laboratory.app.entity;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Table(name="patient")
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long patientId;

    @Column(name="FileNo")
    private int fileNo;
    @Column(name="PatientName", nullable=false)
    private String patientName;
    @Column(name="PatientSurname", nullable=false)
    private String patientSurname;
    @Column(name="PatientDisease", nullable=false)
    private String patientDisease;
    @Column(name="DiagnosisInfo", nullable=false)
    private String diagnosisInfo;
    @Column(name="PatientSecurityNumber", nullable=false)
    private Long patientSecurityNumber;
    @Column
    private LocalDate dateAdded;

}
```

my repo:

```
package com.laboratory.app.repository;
import com.laboratory.app.entity.Patient;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, Long> {

    List<Patient> findAll(); // lists all the patients

    List<Patient> findAllByOrderByDateAddedAsc(); // show data by newest to oldest

    List<Patient> findAllByOrderByDateAddedDesc(); // show data by oldest to newest

    void deleteById(Long id);

    long count(); // return how many patients are there

    Optional<Patient> findById(Long id); // return the @Entity by id

    <S extends Patient> S save(S patient); // saves the patient into the database


    // show related data regarding searched name (case)
    List<Patient> findAllByPatientNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);
    List<Patient> findAllByPatientSurnameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);

}
```

service:

```
package com.laboratory.app.service;
import com.laboratory.app.entity.Patient;
import com.laboratory.app.repository.PatientRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class PatientService {
    @Autowired
    PatientRepository patientRepository;

    public List<Patient> listAllPatients() {
        return patientRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void savePatient(Patient patient) {
        patientRepository.save(patient);
    }

    public void deletePatient(Long id) {
        patientRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public long getPatientNum() {
        return patientRepository.count();
    }

    public Optional<Patient> findPatientById(Long id) {
        return patientRepository.findById(id);
    }


    public List<Patient> findPatientByName(String name) {
        return patientRepository.findAllByPatientNameContainingIgnoreCase(name);
    }

    public List<Patient> findPatientBySurname(String surname) {
        return patientRepository.findAllByPatientSurnameContainingIgnoreCase(surname);
    }

    public List<Patient> getAllPatientsSortedByDateAdded(boolean ascending) {
        if (ascending) {
            return patientRepository.findAllByOrderByDateAddedAsc();
        } else {
            return patientRepository.findAllByOrderByDateAddedDesc();
        }
    }

}
```

and controller:

```
package com.laboratory.app.controller;
import com.laboratory.app.entity.Patient;
import com.laboratory.app.service.PatientService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class PatientController {

    // Patient service object
    @Autowired
    private PatientService patientService;

    @GetMapping(value="/register_patient")
    public ModelAndView registerPatient(Model model) {
        ModelAndView registerView = new ModelAndView("patient/registerPatient");
        Patient newPatient = new Patient();
        model.addAttribute("patient", newPatient);
        return registerView;
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/save")
    public ModelAndView savePatient(@ModelAttribute("patient") Patient patient) {
        patientService.savePatient(patient);
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("patient/doneSuccessfully");
        return view;
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/delete")
    public ModelAndView deletePatient(@RequestParam("patientId") String id) {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("patient/deleted");
        patientService.deletePatient(Long.valueOf(id));
        return view;
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/view_database")
    public ModelAndView viewDatabase(Model model) {
        List<Patient> theEmployees = patientService.listAllPatients();
        model.addAttribute("patients", theEmployees);
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("viewDatabase");
        return view;
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/update")
    public ModelAndView updateDatabase(@RequestParam("patientId") String id, Model model) {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("patient/updatePatient");
        Patient updatedPat = patientService.findPatientById(Long.valueOf(id)).get();
        model.addAttribute("patient", updatedPat);
        return view;
    }
}
```

there's no problem dealing with creating or deleting data, however each time when i want to update existing data, my code creates a new patient data.

couldn't find the solution on possible duplicates. i would like to provide any additional information you need. thank you.

Comment: Could you please share your Patient entity code and the json which is being passed to the savePatient REST method. It looks like you have no id in it, or the entity is configured incorrectly

Comment: Debugging is the best way to find out what is not working as expected. 1. Set breakpoints at the beginning of save and update methods in the controller class. 2. Click the submit button on the UI. 3. One of the breakpoints should be catched. 4. Is this the right method? If yes go line by line and check the flow and variables if as expected. If not - change the href in the UI. These are the steps I would take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that you're just persisting what is passed in.  This is not an attached entity, so it creates a new one.  The way to handle this is to first query the database to retrieve the entity that matches the id that's passed in, then update the fields to what is passed in, then call save on this.

Consider another change, don't use the same post method for create and update, use a PUT to follow the HTTP spec.  It can have the same URL.

Here is an example of what your controller would look like.

```
@PutMapping(value="/save")
public ModelAndView savePatient(@ModelAttribute("patient") Patient patient) {
    patientService.updatePatient(patient);
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("patient/doneSuccessfully");
    return view;
}
```

And the accompanying service

```
public void updatePatient(Patient patient) {
    Patient persistedPatient = patientRepository.findById(patient.get PatientId());

    // Do the work here to update the fields on persistedPatient from patient.
    persistedPatient.setFileNo(patient.getFileNo());
    persistedPatient.setPatientName(patient.getPatientName());
    // ... etc
    
    // save back the persistedPatient
    patientRepository.save(persistedPatient);
}
```

Or, better yet, use a PATCH mapping and use json-patch. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200142/spring-rest-partial-update-with-patch-method/45200650#45200650)

Comment: well that's an info! however, in many tutorials i saw just `patientRepository.save(patient)` method in `@Service` layer, so although that i pass already existing user, it creates a new one. maybe i don't know how to update an existing data. can you just show me a simple example and maybe i can convert it to my code? thank you very much!

Comment: @AnkaraUniFedaisi If you look at the answer, under the comment that says, "Do the work here..", you simply need to set the values from the object passed in to the entity.  I've updated the answer to demonstrate setting a couple fields, just add in the rest

Comment: i forgot to answer again, i did it. thank you.