Should I manually update an entity in spring boot?
I want to know the best and efficient way to update an entity, which is industry practice. What I know at this moment to update an entity
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repository;

    public Student findById(Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Student not found with id: " + id));
    }

    public Student updateStudent(Long id, Student updatedData) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        
        Student existingStudent = findById(id);

       
        existingStudent.setFirstName(updatedData.getFirstName()); 
        existingStudent.setLastName(updatedData.getLastName());
        existingStudent.setEmail(updatedData.getEmail());
        existingStudent.setDepartment(updatedData.getDepartment());
        existingStudent.setPhone(updatedData.getPhone());

        return repository.save(existingStudent);
    }
}


Here I had to manually set all the fields. If I had 20+ fields, was it an efficient approach to update an entity? What is the efficient approach to do that?

Consider using JsonPatch, or some other patching mechanism.  See my answer to another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200142/spring-rest-partial-update-with-patch-method/45200650#45200650

As long as the entity is still attached/managed, we do not need to call an explicit repository.save(...). To assert that this works, we should annotate method updateStudent(...) with @Transactional

One more way is
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private  EntityManager em;
 
    public Student findById(Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Student not found with id: " + id));
    }
    @Transactional()
    public Student updateStudent(Long id, Student updatedData) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        //check if id is present or not

        updatedData.setId(id)

        return em.merge(updatedData);
    }
}

So instead of copying the entity value to the existing entity, you can just set the id in the update entity and call the merge function in the entity manager. The merge function first makes a select call of the entity of the id which fetces the latest data and updates the entity in db. @Transactional makes sure if there is any error during merge function it just rollsback the tranction therefore preventing partial failure

Can I ask you why did you choose pure JPA instead of Spring data JPA?

There are multiple ways in which you can achieve this. One is using the 'ModelMapper' library.
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public Student findById(Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Student not found with id: " + id));
    }

    public Student updateStudent(Long id, Student updatedData) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        Student existingStudent = findById(id);

        // Map properties from updatedData to existingStudent
        modelMapper.map(updatedData, existingStudent);

        return repository.save(existingStudent);
    }
}


I prefer the next approach:
We use "Entity" object that relates to database and "Data Transfer Object" (DTO) that is simple Java bean (POJO - Plain Old Java Object). In simplest case both objects have the same fields. DTO serves for interacting with frontend and passed to and from. Entity describes database structure.
So the data flow for updating the entity will be:
Controller (DTO) -> Service(DTO->Entity) -> Repository(Entity)
In your case "Student" is "Entity" and "updatedStudent" should be StudentDTO with the same fields as in entity.
For updating the entity we have to copy all fields from StudentDTO to Student. That is a case that you asked.
Fortunately you are not alone and this problem was solved by mapstruct https://mapstruct.org/ Mapstruct gives an easy way for mapping DTO to Entity and vice verse.
Include this library as dependency in your project like
implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'

After that you can write an interface for mapping like
@Mapper(component = "spring")
public interface StudentDtoToStudentMapper {
    
    Student convert(StudentDO updatedStudent);

}

Then, instead of copying all fields, use it in your service
@Autowired
StudentDTOToStudentMapper mapper;

// don't need to find a student, just create entity
Student student = mapper.convert(studentDTO);
// and save it
repository.save(student);
...


Hi, Alex. For clarification, should I make a separate DTO class for each entity?

Yes. For the first sight DTO and Entity are the same, but their responsibilities are different. DTO serves for interacting with user and validate user input. Entity serves for interacting with database.

What I get from your statement, if I make 100 entities, then 100 DTO classes should be made. Isn't that terrific?

It's normal. I have 320 entities and 320 dto. I had to write a code generator to produce them and corresponding mappers. If you already have 100 entities consider writing a code generator transforming them. If you have database with 100 tables consider writing a generator transforming table DDL to Java code

If you use Spring Data, your task is very easy: you set the ID and save the object:
public Student updateStudent(Long id, Student updatedData) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    updatedData.setId(id);
    return repository.save(updatedData);
}

If you need an extra method in a service for this depends on your class designs.
