PATCH Spring Data Rest not working as expected
I can't share specific code snippets from my current application, but the structure mainly consists of Entities and Repository classes.
We're encountering an issue with the PATCH method. The expected behavior is that it will partially update only the fields present in the request body. However, we're seeing that if some fields in the request body are omitted, those fields in child entities are being set to NULL.
This isn't the desired behavior, as we want to perform partial updates—fields that are not included in the request should retain their existing values and not be updated to NULL. How can we resolve this to ensure that only the fields in the request body are updated?
We have tried transferring to another domain with same configuration, but it works fine as expected.

Check this out: Using JSON Patch in Spring REST APIs

This question is similar to: Spring REST partial update with @PATCH method. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This link can be useful for your use case, implementing the Patch should follow some conventions and there are a lot of librairies to do so, https://jsonpatch.com/

@lcnicolau my scenario is different from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200142/spring-rest-partial-update-with-patch-method I am using Spring Data REST and I am utilizing the most basic structure it can offer. I only have Repository and Entities only.

This issue occurred after upgrading Spring Boot from 3.2.x to 3.3.x.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

While triggering the Patch request if you include the fields that doesn't need to be updated as null you will face this issue. Include only the attributes that needs to be updated.
Also make sure you are sending the JSON object correctly.
If these things are taken care of it should work fine.

In this scenario, I did not include fields that doesn't need to be included. But i'm still encountering this issue and having a hard time to debug since we only have entities and repository class.

I have added logging for spring data rest in DEBUG level and the only info I got is that, it is utilizing patchItemResource method from RepositoryRestController class by Spring. So we still have no idea why this issue is occurring.

Can you please paste the error you are getting in the post.

I am not encountering error. It's the behavior that is not aligned with the expected behavior. We are expecting PATCH to partially update the fields that are only included in request data, but currently, we are JPA/Hibermate is replacing the entire entity, instead of just partially updating it
